# Stop function from other

Tags: jquery

I have problem with function, I need stop this from other , for example :

My function :

```
<script>

    function caller(activate)
    {

        if (activate=="on")
        {    
            setTimeout(function() {
            alert("ok");       
            },1000)    
        }

         /// Stop function 
         else {

         }

     }

</script>
```

I can call this function when load the page as this

```
<script>
    caller('on');
</script>
```

When the page load finally i´ll receive the alert

But i have other code inside the page for try to stop the function :

```
<script>

    $("#push").click(function() {

        caller('stop');
    });

</script>
```

The problem for this it´s how I have the function load when load the page (caller) when I try stop I can´t stop this and continue, how I can load the function and by other side or to the same time stop.

Comment: `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` is the way to deal with it

Comment: Where i must use clearTimeout()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout returns an ID that can be used to clear the timeout:

```
vat timeoutID;
function caller(activate)
{

    if (activate=="on")
    {    
        timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
        alert("ok");       
        },1000)    
    }

     /// Stop function 
     else {             
         clearTimeout(timeoutID);
         timeoutID = null;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exemple

```
var timeoutGlobalReference ; // Storing the setTimeout return value which is a kind of id

function caller(){
    timeoutGlobalReference = setTimeout(function(){alert("ok");},5000);    
}

// Timeout get initiated
caller();

// Prevent the function from being executed if it hasn't already been called by setTimeout
clearTimeout(timeoutGlobalReference);
```